# Vert.x WebClient stuck in damaged state, only service restart helped

Tags: java, vert.x, vert.x-webclient

I ran into an issue and would like to get your input about how I can avoid this from happening.

- Service A sends HTTP requests ( `vertx-web-client version 4.2.4`) to Service B (`vertx-web-graphql version 4.2.4`)
- Service B crashed
- Service A started receiving timeouts
  the number of active connections spiked to 10x the amount of open connections
- Service B recovered
- Service A, managed to get some calls performed, but kept on failing, all requests that have failed did not end properly (custom router handlers were not called - Vert.x router logged - `Unhandled exception in router`)
  The problem was resolved only by restarting Service A, even though it's vitals were ok.
  Service A did perform the requests using a retrier.

My question is - is there any configurations I could change in the WebClient to avoid this kind of issue?
My understanding is that the failed connections were unstable or in some kind of unusable state - is there a way to reset them if it reaches this point?

[image: Metrics]

Thanks

Comment: are you confusing the server with the webclient? `unahndled exception in router` comes from your http server - the endpoint failed probably because the webclient couldn't do the request. What part do you want to fix? the client or the server?

Comment: Right, the thing is - when you have failures, you return a failure response, and then a new requests comes in and service B was already online so you would expect things to get working, but the failures persisted until I restarted the service. This tells me something is wrong with the Vert.x client, as if it's open connections were stuck in some kind of broken state that it failed to recover from. I'm asking if this is something that can be fixed by configuration, or maybe it's just a bug on Ver.x side?

Comment: @AsadAwadia in addition, I ran into this SO post which is pretty similar
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77625114/vertx-web-request-timing-out-when-getting-connection-from-pool

Comment: post your webclient configuration and setup code

Comment: @AsadAwadia I used the default configurations, with the following retry policy:

```maxAttempts: 3
delayInMilliSeconds: 500
maxDelayInMilliSeconds: 1000```